# How to add keypress event to table td?

Tags: html, html-table, keypress

I have a table like this, for example:

```
<table id="tblUser">
     <td> 1 </td>
     <td> 2 </td>
     <td> 3 </td>
</table>
```

I want to detect the key code when a user presses any key within table cells.

Here is my current code, though it's not working for me:

```
$("#tblUser").keypress(function(e)
{
     alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: How would a key press even reach those `<td>`s? If there were text `<input>`s within the `<td>`s, your question would make more sense.

Comment: I have a table show list of users and need to implement search that works with shortcut. when a key is press then a searchbox show and table cell value is need in search box