# How can I get the value of current td column value on KeyPress method given in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the current column value in keypress   event given in javascript. Here is the code

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("td").keypress(function (e) {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var rownumber = tr.index();
            var colname = $(this).attr("class");            
        });
        
        if(colname == 'HolidayHrs')
        {
          var holidayhrs = the column value of the current row
        }
 })
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="HolidayHrs"><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs</a><input  asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs" type="hidden" class="bros"/></td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994730/how-to-add-keypress-event-to-table-td. `td` doesn't have a keypress event. It's not an input field.

Comment: I am getting keypress event there . If  I  print  the  console.log("KeyPress") inside the keypress function ,I would get that message. So I  am hoping somehow we can get that current column value from the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get html code of td,you can use:

```
var holidayhrs=$(this).html();
```

If you only want to get the text of `<a>` link,you can use:

```
var holidayhrs = $(this).find("a:eq(0)").text();
```

Here is a demo：

html:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="HolidayHrs"><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">HolidayHrs</a><input name="HolidayHrs"  class="bros" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

js(put `if` into function of keypress):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("td").keypress(function (e) {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var rownumber = tr.index();
            var colname = $(this).attr("class");
            if (colname == 'HolidayHrs') {
                var holidayhrs1 = $(this).html();

                var holidayhrs = $(this).find("a:eq(0)").text();

            }
        });

        
    })
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you want to get the newest data of input,you can try to use onchange event.Here is a demo:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="HolidayHrs"><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">HolidayHrs</a><input name="HolidayHrs" class="bros" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$("td input").change(function () {
            var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
            var rownumber = tr.index();
            var colname = $(this).parent('td').attr("class");
            if (colname == 'HolidayHrs') {
                var holidayhrs = $(this).val();


            }
        });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. But When I have used the above code the new value of the holidayhrs is not being showed . for example initially  the value of the column was 0 then I have changed into 10.   But the holidayhrs variable  being showed as 0 .  Then I changed into 20, after that the variable being showed as 10. Is there anyway can I trigger the latest value either in keypress event or in out of focus from that column to any where , Please can you advise me

Comment: if I use var holidayhrs = $(this).html();  The html definition being showed  with the column old value. How can I trigger the latest value of the column somehow  either from keypress  event of the column or when we move out of the focus from that column to anywhere

Comment: So you mean you change the value of the input,and you want to get the new value of input.

Comment: exactly, I am looking for the new value somehow from that column either from keypress else the pointer  after  moving out of that column.

Comment: What new value you mean?I can only see a input in the td.And you can change its value.Can you give an example what you do to change values?

Comment: For example on the input  if the old value is  5, Then I changed 6.30.  Once I  change the existing value.  The holidayhrs variable must be stored with 6.30. At the moment is given with 5. if I change it gain into 7.00, then the variable is given 5.  The newly  edited value  is not given.Always the variable  being showed with just previous value.

Comment: Somewhere I read the keyup event will help to get the latest value rather than using Keypress. . Is that true. if so please can you help ?

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can refer to it.

Comment: Many Thanks  Yiyi You .  But my input type is hidden. I have given in my original post. So the change function is not being called while changing the holiday hrs

Comment: Yiyi You is there any solution on this link ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field